# Shift + Caps Lock でなく Caps Lock で Caps Lock をオンにしたい

Tags: windows, windows-10, key-mapping

https://superuser.com/questions/38323/use-shift-caps-lock-instead-of-caps-lock

上記のリンク先に書かれているように、Windows で Caps Lock を有効にするには US/UK キーボードでは `Caps Lock` キーを押すだけでいいのに対し、日本語キーボードだと `Shift` キー + `Caps Lock` キーと同時に2個キーを押さないといけないのですが、この挙動を US/UK キーボードの方式に戻すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

できれば AutoHotKey などの追加のソフトウェアをインストールしなくてもいい方法（ `regedit` などを使った方法）を教えてください。